# How to install and run rodeo-python in another devices/disks?

Tags: python, linux, installation, ubuntu-14.04, rodeo

I want to install [rodeo software](https://github.com/yhat/rodeo) in my ubuntu 14.04. Because of the lack of space in my Ubuntu system drive I want to install rodeo in another device/disk. I have python 2.7.6,numpy,matplotlib installed in my system without IPython / Jupyter  library.

Do I just download the [deb file](http://bareback.s.yhat.com/) of rodeo and then copy it on the devices/disk and double click the deb file? whether this will install the file  in that device only? What kind of steps should I follow to install rodeo in disk other than the system disk?

or should I try [like this](http://www.marsja.se/installing-rodeo-1-0-linux/)

```
#!/bin/sh

wget -O tmp.zip https://www.yhat.com/products/rodeo/downloads/linux_64 

sudo unzip tmp.zip -d /media/dev1/Rodeo/ && rm tmp.zip
sudo ln -s /media/dev1/Rodeo/Rodeo-linux-x64/Rodeo /media/dev1/Rodeo/
```

where `/media/dev1/Rodeo/` is the rodeo folder in another drive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Challenges of Installing Packages on Ubuntu onto a Separate Drive

On Ubuntu, packages aren't installed in just one directory, such as `Program Files` in Windows OS. The reason for this is that packages installed on Ubuntu, unlike Windows, follow the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LinuxFilesystemTreeOverview#Main_directories). A very well-written explanation of this can be found in [this answer on the AskUbuntu StackExchange site](https://askubuntu.com/a/320655).

Briefly, here is a digestible explanation of the installation procedure for packages on Ubuntu:

> user-level executables are installed in `usr/share/bin`, documentation in `/usr/share/doc`, system-wide config files in `/etc`, library files in `/usr/share/lib`, and so on. I have taken this information from a post on another forum site

You can read more about the difficulties of choosing a single installation path in Ubuntu on that [Ubuntu Forums post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2224879&p=13027357#post13027357).

### Installing Your Package to A Separate Drive

**Before I Continue:**

It is important to note that if you follow either of these approaches, you can simply install the package as per the installation instructions provided with the package. There is no need to specify the directory explicitly as you do in the sample commands you have provided. In fact, I hope that the explanation I provided above of the file-system organization in Ubuntu has convinced you that explicitly providing a directory won't necessarily do what you would think (as it would in Windows if you specified a directory other than `Program Files`).

**Your Options:**

I suggest one of two options:

1. Move the mount point of the system directory that your package will be installed to into another drive. The directories of interest are *usually*:

   - `/usr`: majority of user utilities and applications
   - `/opt`: software which is not handled by the package manager
   - `/media`: data stored on external devices
2. Install / Add a new hard drive (or partition of a hard drive) to Ubuntu.

For both of these options, I would recommend backing up your data somewhere using `rsync` before you proceed. Just in case something doesn't go according to plan, you wouldn't want to lose all of the data stored in one of your system directories!

**Option 1: Moving the Mount Point**

Simply, you must edit the mount point the `fstab` file located in the `/etc` system directory. For your case, say that your `/usr` directory is stored located on the hard drive at `/dev/hda12` and you would like to install user applications on the hard drive at `/dev/hda6`. Then, you would edit the line in your `fstab` file reading `/dev/hda12 /usr ...` to `/dev/hda6 /usr ...`.

The mount points for every directory are specified in that file, so whenever you would like to move a folder that contains a lot of data (usually the folders I mentioned above) to a hard drive with more space, you can simply move that folder to the other hard drive while keeping the rest of your system exactly as it was when Ubuntu was installed! Remember to keep in mind which partitions you are using for Ubuntu, or you might reformat a partition on accident if you're sharing a drive between OS's.

As all of the necessary information is already very well laid-out... if you would like more detailed information or debugging help, I would recommend that you follow the Advanced Example provided in this [Ubuntu Community Guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MoveMountpointHowto#Advanced_Example).

**Option 2: Installing / Adding a New Drive**

This is essentially the same as the the first option, except the hard drive must be formatted first (by [GParted](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowtoPartition/CreatingPartitions) or the [`fdisk` command](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingANewHardDrive#Command_Line_Partitioning) in terminal). Then, you create a new mount point according to the same instructions provided in the first option.

I hope that this helps you, happy coding!